# OctoberCMS backend main menu having sub menus of different plugins into it

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I have one requirement in OctoberCMS which I want to implement backend (Admin side) and here below what I want to implement.

I am using [Builder Plugin](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) and I already have created so many plugins which are showing at the top of header with their respective names and links in admin (backend). And if I click on it, I can do whatever I want (CRUD operation) which works fine for all those plugins.

But now I want only one main menu (Say for example - "**Plugins**") and If I click on it or hover on it, I should weather be able to see all the listed plugins which I will add and can able to add in future if I create more.

I should be able to see those plugin links on hover or on left side and it should have an ability to add/remove those links.

Currently I am trying to do this in builder plugin *backend menu* but I am unable to do so as it is keep conflicting with *code* field for those menu tab. Hence I am now looking forward with some other way if I can implement.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys, Eventually, I was able to make it work. This is what I have done below

Say for example, I have 2 plugins called as **Partners** and **Properties**.

In **Partners** plugin, I have coded something like this in my **Plugin.php** file.

**plugins\technobrave\partners\Plugin.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Partners;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Backend;
use Event;
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    public function registerNavigation()
    {
        return [
            'modules' => [
                'label'       => 'Modules',
                'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/properties/properties'),
                'icon'        => 'icon-bars',
                'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Property.*'],

                'sideMenu'    => [
                    'properties' => [
                            'label' => 'Properties',
                            'icon'        => 'icon-home',
                            'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/properties/properties'),
                            'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Property.*']
                    ],
                    'partner' => [
                            'label' => 'Partners',
                            'icon'        => 'icon-thumbs-up',
                            'url'         => Backend::url('technobrave/partners/partners'),
                            'permissions' => ['Technobrave.Partner.*']

                    ], 
                     ]
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Here, as you can see above, My header menu link will redirect to **Properties** plugin as per my requirement and for left side bar menus, my first link will also be redirected to **Properties** plugin and next sub menu link will be redirected to **Partners** plugin.

Then I went to Partners controller and put code something like below.

**plugins\technobrave\partners\controllers\Partners.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Partners\Controllers;

use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use BackendMenu;

class Partners extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();             
        BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'partner');        
    }
}
```

Here above, as you can see, I have just **executed** the menu into partners plugin to be able to show it when I am inside partners listing or at CRUD operation or somewhere.

Similar thing I have done for **Properties** plugin as well to be able to show menu in **Properties** plugin. This is how my code looks like.

**plugins\technobrave\properties\controllers\Properties.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Properties\Controllers;
use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use BackendMenu;
class Properties extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();       
        BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'properties');
    }
}
```

One thing to note here in this code   `BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'properties');`

The Last argument is different than what we have put in **Partners** plugin. 
`BackendMenu::setContext('Technobrave.Partners', 'modules', 'properties');`
This is to set as default selected menu from the list at left sidebar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate menu by creating a boot() function in you plugin.

Exemple from 
https://github.com/scottbedard/blogtags/blob/master/Plugin.php#L54

```
    class Plugin extends PluginBase
    {

        public function pluginDetails()
        {
            [..]
        }

        public function boot()
        {
            // extend the blog navigation
            Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) {
               $manager->addSideMenuItems('RainLab.Blog', 'blog', [
                    'tags' => [
                        'label' => 'bedard.blogtags::lang.navigation.tags',
                        'icon'  => 'icon-tags',
                        'code'  => 'tags',
                        'owner' => 'RainLab.Blog',
                        'url'   => Backend::url('bedard/blogtags/tags')
                    ]
                ]);
            });
}
```

To remove menu items you can use

- $manager->removeMainMenuItem()
- $manager->removeSideMenuItem()

API documentation for the navigation manager : https://octobercms.com/docs/api/backend/classes/navigationmanager

Comment: Hi @MittulAtTechnoBrave did you manage to solve having one side menu for multiple plugins?